# Can you access css file from git/shared drive for shared use by company?

Tags: css, r, shiny, r-markdown

Is there a better way for programmers within a group, looking to share a common style for shiny apps or rmarkdown docs, to access a css file from a single location rather than manually copying the desired file into the subcontents of each app or document?

The ideal outcome would be to place the file(s) on a github repo, then attach it to any shiny app or rmarkdown file with its web link, is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It might be easier to include your stylesheets in an R package. This would eliminate the need for external request each time your app loads or doc is opened. Place your css files in a folder in `inst` and write a single R function that sets the resource paths to your css and loads files accordingly.

Let's say your package has the following structure. (For this example, I'm naming the package `mypkg`)

```
mypkg/
  R/
    use_stylesheets.R
  inst/
    stylesheets/
      styles.min.css
      ...
  ...
```

In `use_stylesheets.R`, create a function that loads the stylesheets into the head of the document (`tags$head`) using `tags$link`.

```r
use_stylesheets <- function() {

  shiny::addResourcePath(
    "styles",
    system.file("stylesheets", package = "mypkg")
  )

  shiny::tags$head(
    shiny::tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "styles.min.css")
  )

}
```

Then in your app or Rmarkdown document, you can load the files into your app using: `mypkg::use_stylesheets()`

Comment: I haven't quite been able to have this work, but I have confidence that this is the correct path forward, both for adding a css file, as well as an html header or footer. 

I also wonder if `styles.min.css` should be changed to `styles/styles.min.css` to reflect that relative path from the resourcePath created in the function.

My issue currently is that neither rmarkdown documents or shiny apps appear to be successfully adding these files to the head of the output, as evident when using inspect from the browser.

Comment: You are correct. Adding `styles/` should load the files. I would also consider using the `zzz.R` and `htmlDependency` approach. This is probably a bit easier if you want to use files in more than one function. Use in the functions `.onLoad` to add an new resource and `.onUnload` to remove it. See chapter 7 of the R Package Development ebook for more information.

Comment: I was looking to add some functionality to your function above to select which css file or html footer to use based on the user and the desired output. With that in mind I don't know if an `.onLoad` approach will allow that flexibility.

The above structure that you answered with is the desired performance, I'm just not sure why the attachment using the `shiny::tags` functions aren't working or how to debug.

Comment: It's a bit hard to say what could be the issue. Check the browser's dev console for any messages. It might also be worth checking the package structure post-installation (i.e., in your R library path) to see if there's anything weird going. Make sure your assets are stored in `inst/some-folder/`. One of the r package's that I have been working on uses a similar approach, checkout [browsertools](https://github.com/davidruvolo51/browsertools). For examples, see the `R/zzz.R`, `R/use_browserstools.R` and the dev app `dev/dev-app/app.R` files.

Comment: Upon some further testing I was able to have success with the shiny::addResourcePath()` approach for attaching them to shiny apps, and my below approach for Rmarkdown. I will update my answer when I have a moment.

Answer (score 2):

After some tinkering I was able to have success (waiting on coworkers to test on their machines) using these structures for adding css or html from a package into both Shiny Apps and Rmarkdown documents.

```
# For attaching a css file to an Rmarkdown file
use_package_style_rmd <- function(css_file = "my_css.css"){
  # css file
  file_name <- paste0("/", css_file)
  file_path <- paste0(system.file("stylesheets", package = "my_pkg"), file_name)
  shiny::includeCSS(path = file_path)
}


# For placing an HTML headers/footers in place
use_package_header <- function(html_file = "my_header.html"){
  # HTML Header
  file_name <- paste0("/", html_file)
  file_path <- paste0(system.file("stylesheets", package = "my_pkg"), file_name)
  shiny::includeHTML(path = file_path)
}


# For attaching css to a shiny app via resourcePath
use_package_style_shiny <- function(stylesheet = "my_css.css"){

  # Add Resource Path
  shiny::addResourcePath(
    prefix = "styles",
    directoryPath = system.file("stylesheets", package = "my_pkg"))

  # Link to App
  shiny::tags$head(
      shiny::tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", 
      href = paste0("styles/", stylesheet)))
}
```

The `use_package_style_rmd` function can be placed in any code chunk, whereas the header function will add the html in-place where the function is run.

For the Shiny app use-case the function should be run to establish the resource path to the folder, then in the UI under `fluidpage` the theme option can be set to the css file using the prefix for the Resource Path `styles/my_css.css`.

One issue I am still having which may be a separate question, is where to place a supporting image file, and how to add the relative path such that the image can be placed in the header or footer.

Comment: hey this is great! did you find out how to add the image/logo to the css package?